# EF 4.1 Saving record creates record for lookup table

Tags: c#, frameworks, entity, ef-code-first

Here are my classes

```
public class Activity
{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public string Personnel { get; set; }
    public Location Location { get; set; }
}

public class Location
{
    [Key]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

When I save an Activity it creates a new Location, even if it already exists. How do I set it up so it uses existing Locations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load the existing `Location` through the context and use that as the property value of the `Activity`

eg:

```
using(var context = new MyDbContext())
{
   var location = context.Locations.FindByKey(/* set key*/);
   var activity = new Activity(){Personnel = "Foo", Location = location};
   context.Activities.Add(activity);
   context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This works but I'm confused as to why I would have to make this check. The Location class/table only has one field and it's the key.

Comment: @aboes81 if you don't load or attach manually, EF treats the `Location` object as new.

Answer (score 0):

Add the Key attribute to Activity.ID, just like you have for Location.Name

```
public class Activity
{
    [Key]
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public string Personnel { get; set; }
    public Location Location { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is the issue. EF 4.1 has a convention that automatically assigns properties called ID or <ClassName>ID the key if no [Key] attributes are used.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to attach the location to the context before adding the Activity:

```
using(var context = new MyDbContext())
{
    var location = new Location { Name = "MyName" };
    context.Locations.Attach(location);

    var activity = new Activity { Personnel = "Foo", Location = location };
    context.Activities.Add(activity);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

It saves you to fetch the location from the DB.

Another option (which requires to change the model though) is to expose the foreign key for location to the Activity class:

```
public class Activity
{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public string Personnel { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Location")]
    public string LocationName { get; set; }
    public Location Location { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can simply assign the FK value:

```
using(var context = new MyDbContext())
{
    var activity = new Activity { Personnel = "Foo", LocationName = "MyName" };
    context.Activities.Add(activity);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Leave the `Location` navigation property `null` in this case.